# route trafic between 2 wireguards tunnels

Tags: networking, iptables, ssh-tunneling, route

Here is my arch on my local network :

Machines schema :

`<wg_client_1 (int`wg1`)> ----- <(int`wg1`) wg_term_1 (int`wg0`)> ----- <(int`wg0`) wg_term_2 (int eth2)>`

Network schema :

`<||wg_client_1|| (int wg1 : 10.242.0.2)(10.242.0.0/24 network)> ----- <(int wg1 : 10.242.0.1)(10.242.0.0/24 network)||wg_term_1||(int wg0 : 10.241.0.1)(10.241.0.0/24 network)> ----- <(int wg0 : 10.241.0.2)(10.241.0.0/24 network) ||wg_term_2|| (int eth2 :10.243.0.1) (10.243.0.0/24 network)>`

- All the machines are VMs on my local network
- All the machines have "real" adresses (`192.168.123.0/24`) but I want them to communicate through the tunnels. Im connected on the machines with SSH using their adresses which are in the `192.168.123.0/24` network.
- I've set up a tunnel between `wg_client_1`(int `wg1`) and  `wg_term_1` (int `wg1`). The tunnel is working. `wg_term_1` can ping `10.242.0.2`, and `wg_client_1` can ping `10.242.0.1`.
- I've set up a tunnel between `wg_term_1` and `wg_term_2`. This tunnel is also working. `wg_term_1` can ping `10.241.0.2`, and `wg_term_2` can ping `10.241.0.1`.

Here is the result of the `wg` command on `wg_client_1` :

```
# wg
interface: wg1
  public key: yQO6xpv+3HC+xTyfxzC503vr+E84VBnphntfwFJXREA=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 49149

peer: CywdYs8L0TD7zLvMqHnqL/N2WoqRmDuDvn6skg+8wUc=
  endpoint: 192.168.123.21:51821
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/8
  latest handshake: 8 seconds ago
  transfer: 11.39 KiB received, 236.84 KiB sent
```

Here is the result of the `wg` command on `wg_term_1` :

```
# wg
interface: wg1
  public key: CywdYs8L0TD7zLvMqHnqL/N2WoqRmDuDvn6skg+8wUc=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51821

peer: yQO6xpv+3HC+xTyfxzC503vr+E84VBnphntfwFJXREA=
  endpoint: 192.168.123.23:49149
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/8
  latest handshake: 58 seconds ago
  transfer: 236.84 KiB received, 11.43 KiB sent

interface: wg0
  public key: HGF89Hcphaf+Uua214hSc/mZa/p2vmIUeT6IwrN7I3Y=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: +xTyPmYo9+IPBC72MFzIWFHrQyz5N6v67rjZz3q5CR4=
  endpoint: 192.168.123.22:51820
  allowed ips: 10.241.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 17 seconds ago
  transfer: 10.03 KiB received, 233.33 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Here is the result of the `wg` command on `wg_term_2` :

```
# wg
interface: wg0
  public key: +xTyPmYo9+IPBC72MFzIWFHrQyz5N6v67rjZz3q5CR4=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: HGF89Hcphaf+Uua214hSc/mZa/p2vmIUeT6IwrN7I3Y=
  endpoint: 192.168.123.21:51820
  allowed ips: 10.241.0.1/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 3 seconds ago
  transfer: 1.23 KiB received, 6.79 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Now, I want to route the clients network trafic (`10.242.0.0/24`) in the second tunnel (which is between `wg_term_1` and `wg_term_2`). I want that `wg_client_1` (`10.242.0.1`) can ping `wg_term_2` (`10.241.0.2` or `10.243.0.1`).

So I added these routes to wg_client_1 :

```
ip route add 10.241.0.0/24 via 10.242.0.1
ip route add 10.243.0.0/24 via 10.242.0.1
```

And these routes to wg_term_1 :

```
ip route add 10.242.0.0/24 via 10.242.0.1
ip route add 10.241.0.0/24 via 10.241.0.2
ip route add 10.243.0.0/24 via 10.241.0.2
```

But when I do a `ping 10.241.0.2` from `wg_client_1`, it's not working. 
Here is the tcpdump on wg_term_1 :

```
# tcpdump -i wg0 -i wg1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wg1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
03:58:31.451778 IP 10.242.0.2 > 10.241.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 432, seq 1, length 64
03:58:32.464024 IP 10.242.0.2 > 10.241.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 432, seq 2, length 64
03:58:33.488174 IP 10.242.0.2 > 10.241.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 432, seq 3, length 64
```

And the `tcpdump` on `wg_term_2` isn't showing anything... so the trafic isn't routed...

IPv4 forwarding is enabled on `wg_term_1` and `wg_term_2` : 
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Can anyone explain whats happening and why the trafic isn't routed correctly ?
Thanks

Comment: I rewrote my answer, you should take a look at it, because my former explanation wasn't correct (even if it happened to give a correct result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup><sub>**UPDATE**: rewrote substantial parts of this answer, which while it made OP's question work, was using a flawed explanation which I corrected. The cryptokey association is of course independent between two WireGuard interfaces and not interacting between them. There are interactions only between multiple peers per WireGuard interface, but OP uses only one peer per interface, so didn't have this specific issue here.</sub></sup>

WireGuard's [cryptokey routing](https://www.wireguard.com/talks/fosdem2017-slides.pdf) is an additional layer of routing based on the key, beyond the kernel's standard network stack routing. On each interface it associates the `allowed-ips` with a peer. It's used to route to the correct (of multiple) peer(s) for egress, and also to associate a packet with a given peer for ingress, and accept this packet then. So to communicate properly, one must have correct routes, *and* compatible *allowed-ips* entries on the WireGuard interfaces.

It's not written, but I assume OP also added on *wg_term_2* a route to *wg_client_1*'s LAN , like:

```
10.242.0.0/24 via 10.241.0.1 dev wg0
```

or simply (because it's a layer 3 tunnel so doesn't require a gateway):

```
10.242.0.0/24 dev wg0
```

when *wg_client_1* pings 10.241.0.2 (ie: *wg_term_2*), the packet is:

- routed through *wg1* interface
- cryptorouted to the peer on *wg1* where destination matches its allowed-ips 10.0.0.0/8
- arrives at *wg_term_1* through `UDP 192.168.123.23:49149 -> 192.168.123.21:51821`
- accepted on *wg1* since source matches its allowed-ips 10.0.0.0/8
- routed through *wg0* interface
- cryptorouted to the peer on *wg0* where destination matches its allowed-ips 10.241.0.2/32
- arrives at *wg_term_2* through `UDP 192.168.123.21:51820 -> 192.168.123.22:51820`
- dropped on *wg0* because the source doesn't match any allowed-ips so can't be associated with a peer.

The reverse, from *wg_term_2* to *wg_client_1* (still with the correct route but not the correct *allowed-ips*) generates here a specific error:

```
# ip route get 10.242.0.2
10.242.0.2 via 10.241.0.1 dev wg0 src 10.241.0.2 uid 0 
    cache 
# ping 10.242.0.2
PING 10.242.0.2 (10.242.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.241.0.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
^C
--- 10.242.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

The only minimal setting needed to make this work, is to add *wg_client_1*'s IP address on *wg_term_2*'s *wg0*'s peer allowed ips:

```
# wg set wg0 peer HGF89Hcphaf+Uua214hSc/mZa/p2vmIUeT6IwrN7I3Y= \
    allowed-ips 10.241.0.1/32,10.242.0.2/32
```

One could probably allow the involved LANs instead:

```
# wg set wg0 peer HGF89Hcphaf+Uua214hSc/mZa/p2vmIUeT6IwrN7I3Y= \
     allowed-ips 10.241.0.0/24,10.242.0.0/24
```

And to complete the settings and cryptoroute the 10.243.0.0/24 LAN, this can be set on *wg_term_1* (also rewrote the former /32 to a /24):

```
# wg set wg0 peer +xTyPmYo9+IPBC72MFzIWFHrQyz5N6v67rjZz3q5CR4= \
     allowed-ips 10.241.0.0/24,10.243.0.0/24
```

It could have been possible in this specific case to have a single WireGuard interface on *wg_term_1* with two peers, but then care should have been taken to write the minimal *allowed-ips* entries for each peer: 10.242.0.0/24 (instead of 10.0.0.0/8) on one side and 10.241.0.0/24,10.243.0.0/24 on the other side: contrary to routing where narrower range wins over broader range, WireGuard's cryptorouting doesn't accept any overlap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that clear answer ! Everything is working now !